# Voltar posição em dados formato JSON ou list com Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, lista, dicionário, getjson

Estou trabalhando com dados semelhante a estrutura abaixo:

```
{"Id":1,
"Data_inscricao":"2017-01-01",
"Texto":"Loremipsum",
"Numeracao":26,
"Tempo":"25s"}, 
{"Id":3,
"Data_inscricao":"2010-05-02",
"Texto":"LoremipsumLorem",
"Numeracao":656,
"Tempo":9},....
```

Eu tenho em mãos o dado "656" que faz referência ao "Numeracao". 
Eu preciso voltar 2 posição do meu .get("Numeracao") para pegar o dado "2010-05-02", ou seja, usar o .get("Data_inscricao") mas com referência ao "Numeracao":656

Como faço isso em variável formato JSON ou list?
Código atual abaixo:

```
numeracao = '656'

#A URL é privada, não vou conseguir mostrar o conteúdo
html = urlopen("https://www.teste.com.br")

#Retornando um volume muito grande de dados, não são apenas 2 blocos de registros.
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

informacoes = bsObj.findAll(id="Resultados")
print(informacoes)

    #Resultado do print() - BEGIN

    [<input id=&quot;Resultados&quot; type=&quot;hidden&quot; value=&quot;{

    &quot;result&quot;:true,&quot;message&quot;:&quot;ok&quot;,&quot;Contador&quot;:2282,&quot;Dados&quot;:
    [
    {&quot;Id&quot;:1,
    &quot;Data_inscricao&quot;:&quot;2017-01-01&quot;,
    &quot;Texto&quot;:&quot;Loremipsum&quot;,
    &quot;Numeracao&quot;:26,
    &quot;Tempo&quot;:&quot;25s&quot;}, 
    {&quot;Id&quot;:3,
    &quot;Data_inscricao&quot;:&quot;2010-05-02&quot;,
    &quot;Texto&quot;:&quot;LoremipsumLorem&quot;,
    &quot;Numeracao&quot;:656,
    &quot;Tempo&quot;:9}
    ]

    }&quot;/>]
    #Resultado do print() - END

informacoes = informacoes.replace('&quot;', '\"')
print(type(informacoes))

    #Resultado do print() - BEGIN
    <class 'str'>
    #Resultado do print() - END

print(informacoes)

    #Resultado do print() - BEGIN

    [<input id="Resultados" type="hidden" value="{

    "result":true,"message":"ok","Contador":2282,"Dados":
    [
    {"Id":1,
    "Data_inscricao":"2017-01-01",
    "Texto":"Loremipsum",
    "Numeracao":26,
    "Tempo":"25s"}, 
    {"Id":3,
    "Data_inscricao":"2010-05-02",
    "Texto":"LoremipsumLorem",
    "Numeracao":656,
    "Tempo":9}
    ]

    }"/>]

    #Resultado do print() - END

regex = re.compile('(?:\"Dados\":\[)(.*?)(?:[]}"/>]])')

informacoes = re.findall(regex, informacoes)
print(type(informacoes))

    #Resultado do print() - BEGIN
    <class 'list'>
    #Resultado do print() - END

#Imprime conteúdo, considerando como lista
for dados in informacoes:
    print(type(dados))
        #Resultado do print() - BEGIN
        <class 'str'>
        #Resultado do print() - END

    print(dados)
        #Resultado do print() - BEGIN

        {"Id":1,
        "Data_inscricao":"2017-01-01",
        "Texto":"Loremipsum",
        "Numeracao":26,
        "Tempo":"25s"}, 
        {"Id":3,
        "Data_inscricao":"2010-05-02",
        "Texto":"LoremipsumLorem",
        "Numeracao":656,
        "Tempo":9

        #Resultado do print() - END
    #No print acima, realmente está faltando a } no final, provavelmente é por causa da regex
```

Comment: Tem como detalhar melhor a pergunta? O seu JSON é uma lista de objetos? Qual é o código que você está utilizando até agora?

Comment: @Anderson, não sei ao certo, mas acredito que seja uma lista de objetos pois o JSON, está sendo o retorno de um beautifulsoup. Não tenho uma lógica para esse código ainda

Comment: Tem como colocar o JSON por completo então? Não esqueça do seu código também...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss , coloquei o código

Comment: A pergunta está, no minimo, estranha, o conceito do json é "key:value", então não faz muito sentido a expressao "voltar 2 posicões..", se vc sabe qual é a chave, vá direto nela. Se vc não sabe mas sabe o valor, converta para um dict e procure o valor para descobrir a chave, o problema é se um mesmo valor pertencer a mais de uma chave.

Comment: @Sidon , Sim, um valor pode pertencer a mais de uma chave com o mesmo nome. No caso a expressão "voltar 2 posições", se baseia em eu possuir o valor 656 e precisar coletar o value da key Numeracao, apenas do bloco de dados com id:3. Obs. eu não tenho o value do id

Comment: Sem o arquivo real em mão fica dificil.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para que fique mais claro, poderia analisar fazendo favor?

Comment: @DaniloAlbergardi Ok, coloquei uma resposta, veja se ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que já deram boas respostas aqui, mas vou deixar minha interpretação, até para fazer a análise solicitada nos comentários.
A primeira coisa que observo é que o exemplo que é dado do Json, na verdade não é válido, um json é, em termos de formato, bem semelhante aos dicionários (ou lista deles) do python. Dessa forma, adaptei para o formato mais provável:
 ([tl;dr](https://repl.it/IstP/4)).

```
[  
   {  
      "Id":1,
      "Data_inscricao":"2017-01-01",
      "Texto":"Loremipsum",
      "Numeracao":26,
      "Tempo":"25s"
   },
   {  
      "Id":3,
      "Data_inscricao":"2010-05-02",
      "Texto":"LoremipsumLorem",
      "Numeracao":656,
      "Tempo":9
   }
]
```

Se vc pegar o conteúdo acima, colocar em um arquivo tipo texto com o nome "j1.txt', entrar em um console python e executar os comandos abaixo:

```
with open('/path/j1.txt') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
print (data)
```

O que vc vai obter é exatamente uma objeto do tipo `list` do python, e o `print` vai ser exatamente igual a uma apresentação do txt. Com esse formato correto e "carregado" para o python, podemos fazer o que vc deseja:

```
number = 656
for d in data:
    for value in d.values():
        if value==number:
            print ('A data de inscrição é: ', d['Data_inscricao'])

 A data de inscrição é:  2010-05-02
```

Como eu disse um Json ou um dicionario, não é 'navegável' através de um ponteiro e sim através de suas chaves/valores, então o que eu fiz foi navegar na lista de objetos (essa sim permite navegação tipo ponteiro), descobrir qual objeto possui o valor que voce procura (veja não não me preocupei se a chave é ou não a `Numeracao`, mas poderia te-lo feito, aliás, faço-o em seguida), e finalmente, pegar o valor da `data_inscricao`.

Se vc quiser restringer somente para a chave `Numeração`, poderia fazer assim:

```
# Restringindo para que a busca se limite à chave 'Numeração'
for d in data:
    for key  in d.keys():
        if key=='Numeracao':
            if d[key]==number: 
                print ('A data de inscrição é: ', d['Data_inscricao'])
A data de inscrição é:  2010-05-02
```

Note que em ambos os casos, se o valor 656 aparecer `n` vezes (a primeira restringindo à chave `Numeracao` e a segunda não levando a chave em consideração.), a data da inscrição será apresentada `n` vezes.

**Consideração final**
 
Dá para criar uma estratégia para poder 'voltar', uma ou `n` posições no objeto dentro do json (veja que vc não estaria voltando no json, mas sim no ojeto dentro dele, que nesse caso seria um dicionario), mas considero que isto seria um verdadeiro masoquismo, um caminho seria: Identificar o dicionário em que está o valor procurado, colocar as chaves em uma matriz `mkeys` e os valores em outra `mvalues`, identificar a posição (index) do valor procurado em `mvalues`, voltar as `n` posições desejada em `mkeys`(somente para pegar o nome da chave) e acessar o valor em `mvalues` na mesma posição. A não ser como um mero exercício, não parece sensato.

[Veja o código funcionando no repl.it.](https://repl.it/IstP/4)

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que sua dificuldade está relacionada a como transformar uma string em dicionário. Como você converte o JSON em string para usar o *replace*, você precisa fazer com que o python volte a entende-lo como *dict* para fazer sua consulta. Para conseguir isso você pode usar o built-in json (https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

```
import json

informacoes = '{"resultado":true, "mensagem":"ok", "Contador":2144,\
                "Dados":[{"Id":1, "Data_inscricao":"2017-01-01",\
                          "Texto":"Loremipsum", "Numeracao":26, "Tempo":"25s"},\
                         {"Id":3, "Data_inscricao":"2010-05-02",\
                          "Texto":"LoremipsumLorem", "Numeracao":656, "Tempo":"96s"}]}'

# Diz ao python que sua string deve ser lida como JSON
data = json.loads(informacoes)

# Se você der um print(type(data)) verá que a str passará a ser tratada como dict
```

Depois é só fazer uma busca pelo(s) dicionário(s) pela informação que você quer. Existem várias formas de se fazer isso, e abaixo apenas exemplifico uma delas.

```
numeracao = 656

for dictio in data["Dados"]:
    if dictio["Numeracao"] == numeracao:
        print(dictio["Data_inscricao"])
```

NOTA: Não procure sua numeração como str, pois no JSON ela está como int.

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para que fique mais claro, poderia analisar fazendo favor?

Answer (score 1):

Oi, eu sou programador Java, mas acredito que essa linha de raciocínio funcione pra python...

1 - Você precisa transformar esse JSON numa estrutura de dados do python, ou seja, num array de objetos;

2 - Tendo um array de objetos em mão você precisa filtrar os itens que tenham o valor 656 no atributo "Numeração", talvez já exista uma biblioteca que abstraia bastante coisa pra você, do contrário vai ter que percorrer todos os itens, verificando o valor da propriedade "Numeração" de cada um para retornar 1 objeto que vai ser o que você procura;

3 - Tendo o item (objeto) encontrado você vai acessar a propriedade "Data_inscricao" de dentro dele;

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para que fique mais claro, poderia analisar fazendo favor?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo visto tua dúvida principal não é na conversão de dados para JSON, e sim em extrair os dados do HTML com o BeautifulSoup.

Não tenho tanta familiaridade com o BeautifulSoup, mas pelo que vi na [documentação](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) tu precisa usar o método [`soup.find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) pois o método `soup.findAll()` retorna uma lista de elementos, enquando o `soup.find()` retorna um elemento ou None.

Depois de ter encontrado o elemento é só pegar o atributo que tu quer diretamente no python com [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)(exemplo `elemento['atributo']`).

```py
html = urlopen("https://www.teste.com.br")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# Pega o elemento que tu quer
info = soup.find(id="Resultados")

if info is None:
    # Nenhum elemento encontrado

# pega apenas o atributo que tu quer
json_str = info.get('value')

if json_str is None:
    # Elemento não possui atributo 'value'

# converte para json
json_data = json.loads(json_str)
```

Agora que tu já tem teus dados carregados como JSON é hora de escolher como serão extraídos os dados necessários.

---

Se tu for pesquisar os dados apenas pelo campo `Numeracao` e precisar fazer mais do que 1 pesquisa, tu pode criar um `dict` com o índice sendo o tem campo `Numeracao`, assim a procura no `dict` é rápida (O(1)).

Ex.:

```py
import json

# json_data atribuído no código anterior

dados = { data['Numeracao']: data for data in json_data['Dados'] }

# print(dados)
"""
dados = {
    656: {
        'Tempo': '96s', 
        'Data_inscricao': '2010-05-02', 
        'Id': 3, 
        'Numeracao': 656, 
        'Texto': 'LoremipsumLorem'
    }, 
    26: {
        'Tempo': '25s', 
        'Data_inscricao': '2017-01-01', 
        'Id': 1, 
        'Numeracao': 26, 
        'Texto': 'Loremipsum'
    }
}
"""

# Agora ficou simples e rápido procurar por numeração
numeracao = 656

# retorna o item com chave 656 ou None se o item não existir
item = dados.get(numeracao) 

if item:
    print('Dados encontrados ---> Data_inscricao:', item['Data_inscricao'])
else:
    print('Dados não encontrados')
```

Porém se for pesquisar apenas uma única vez e descartar os dados, tu pode iterar tua lista de dados e pegar apenas o item que tu precisa (O(n)).

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import json

# json_data atribuído no código anterior

# Numeração desejada
numeracao = 656

# Itera json_data['Dados'] e filtra apenas o item que tiver numeração (retorna um generator)
dados = (x for x in json_data['Dados'] if x['Numeracao'] == numeracao)

# Retorna o item com a numeração desejada ou None caso ele não exista
item = next(dados, None)

if item:
    print('Dados encontrados ---> Data_inscricao:', item['Data_inscricao'])
else:
    print('Dados não encontrados')
```

Comment: Alterei a pergunta para que fique mais claro, poderia analisar fazendo favor?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, vê se te ajuda.